# XCode: How do you connect to BLE peripheral via UUID?

Tags: ios, xcode, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid

In my app I am trying to connect to a Bluetooth Low Energy peripheral via. its UUID, but I am not getting any results.

With `[_centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];` I am able to find the peripheral, and in my `if (_discoveredPeripheral != peripheral && [peripheral.name isEqual: @"PeripheralName"])` I am able to connect to my device, but only because it's the only device with that name.

When I try to connect via. UUID 
`myUUID = [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"My UUID"];
[_centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:[NSArray arrayWithObject:myUUID] options:nil];`, I get nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You put the `UUID` into the array with services. You do not have a method to scan for a specific device, only devices with specific services.

Your working version is OK, you simply need to iterate through the results and connect to the desired device. Scanning devices for specific services is used for discovery of devices that can support specific services.

So what you are actually doing wrong is you are inserting peripheral `UUID` into array which expects a service UUID.

Comment: So I should be inputting my Service UUID instead of my device UUID?

I will get on it later today, and make sure to get you a correct answer if it works :) Thank you so much!